# Optimise matrix calculation in R - possible to avoid aperm?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix calculation that I'd like to speed up.

Some toy data and example code:

```
n = 2 ; d = 3
mu <- matrix(runif(n*d), nrow=n, ncol=d)
sig <- matrix(runif(n*d), nrow=n, ncol=d)
x_i <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
not_missing <- !is.na(x_i)

calc1 <-function(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing){
    z <- array( rep(0, length(x_i)*n*d),
                dim = c(length(x_i), n, d))
    
    subtract_term <- 0.5*log(2*pi*sig)
    
    for(i in 1:length(x_i)){
        if( not_missing[i] ){
            z[i, , ] <- ((-(x_i[i] - mu)^2 / (2*sig)) - subtract_term  )
        }
    }
    z <- aperm(z, c( 2, 1, 3))
    return(z)
}

microbenchmark(
    z1 <- calc1(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing)
)
```

In profiling with real data, both the `z[i, , ] <-` line and the `aperm()` line are the slow points. I've been trying to optimise it to avoid calling `aperm` altogether by transposing the 2D matrices earlier to avoid a 3D transpose, but then I cannot put the 3D array together properly. Any help much appreciated.

Edit: I have a partial solution from @G. Grothendieck, which eliminated the aperm, it has not resulted in much speed improvments for some reason. New solution from his answer is:

```
calc2 <-function(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing){
    nx <- length(x_i)
    z <- array( 0, dim = c(n, nx, d))
    
    subtract_term <- 0.5*log(2*pi*sig)
    
    for(i in 1:nx){
        if( not_missing[i] ) {
          z[, i, ] <- ((-(x_i[i] - mu)^2 / (2*sig)) - subtract_term  )
        }
    }
    return(z)
}
```

Speed comparison:

```
> microbenchmark(
+         z1 <- calc1(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing),
+         z2 <- calc2(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing), times = 1000
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                         expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval cld
 z1 <- calc1(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing) 13.586 14.2975 24.41132 14.5020 14.781 9125.591  1000   a
 z2 <- calc2(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing)  9.094  9.5615 19.98271  9.8875 10.202 9655.254  1000   a
```

Comment: Reopened question, as while @G.Grothendieck answer got rid of the aperm, it hasn't led to speed improvements. updating question.

Comment: The performance comparison you posted shows that the median time it took to run was 32% less than the original so it is not true that it did not run faster.

Comment: When I first ran the check there was no difference. I'm unclear why that changed. I managed to vectorise the calculation now but it also makes little difference. Perhaps there is no more speed to be got without going to c++ ?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck well more testing of various options and yours is consistently fastest. I must have mixed myself up somewhere. Thanks for your help 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This eliminates the aperm.

```
calc2 <-function(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing){
    nx <- length(x_i)
    z <- array( 0, dim = c(n, nx, d))
    
    subtract_term <- 0.5*log(2*pi*sig)
    
    for(i in 1:nx){
        if( not_missing[i] ) {
          z[, i, ] <- ((-(x_i[i] - mu)^2 / (2*sig)) - subtract_term  )
        }
    }
    return(z)
} 

z1 <- calc1(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing)
z2 <- calc2(n, d, mu, sig, x_i, not_missing)

identical(z1, z2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Aha! omg is was overthinking it with ```t(mu)``` s and stuff. Many thanks. Oddly enough it didnt' make much speed difference with real data alas.